# Read files to Azure function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have some files stored in **Azure Storage** ,and I want to iterate and read them from **azure function** (in python)
How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to loop through all the containers and directories present in the Storage account.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<SAS TOKEN>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

print("\nList blobs in the container")
containers = blob_service.list_containers() #lists the containers
for cntnr in containers:
    generator = blob_service.list_blobs(cntnr.name) #lists the blobs inside containers
    for blob in generator:
        print("\t Blob name: "+cntnr.name+'/'+  blob.name)
        file=blob_service.get_blob_to_text(cntnr.name,blob.name) #lets you read content directly
        file=blob_service.get_blob_to_path(cntnr.name,blob.name,blob.name) #lets you download the content to local and from there you can read the file
```

Comment: I am still beginner so I wonder from where I cab get ACCOUNT_NAME and SAS_TOKEN  variables ?

Comment: you can get those from your storage account. Please check the attached image https://i.imgur.com/46gGStl.png

Comment: I am using a newer version of azure.storage.blob so BlockBlobService is not available, it replaced by BlobServiceClient

Comment: @Yoshi try using azure-storage-blob==2.1.0 i.e., pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0

Comment: I am already using the latest one in other piece of code so it could help if you can adapt the code to latest azure-storage-blob release

Comment: then try adding what you have tried and where you are receiving errors or blockers in your current code.

Comment: I created a connection string then I have access the blob using  BlobClient.from_connection_string(), I want to know how to access the container list the files and read them using pandas python library

Comment: @Yoshi Try adding the code you tried in your question

Comment: taxes = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str, container_name="containername", blob_name="blob.csv")